# Proof concerning squared norm in a Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

I am currently trying to prove, without success, the following statement

$||\mathbf{x}||^{-2} = \min_{\mathbf{w} \in \mathcal{H}}\{||\mathbf{w}||^2:  \langle\mathbf{w}, \mathbf{x}\rangle = 1\}$,

where $\mathcal{H}$ is a generic Hilbert space, and $\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{H}$.

Can someone help me? At least by giving some hint on how to proceed. The proof should be straightforward, but nonetheless I don't know where to start.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: As a hint, can you see that $$\{\mathbf{w}\in\mathcal{H}:\langle\mathbf{w},\mathbf{x}\rangle=1\}=\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^2}\mathbf{x}+\{\mathbf{v}\in\mathcal{H}:\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{x}\rangle=0\}?$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Sadly I don't see why the equality should be true, could you explain it more in detail? In particular, I am not familiar with the notation on the right part of the equation: does it mean that the set of vectors on the left is equal to the unit vector plus the set of all vectors orthogonal to $\mathbf{x}$?

By the way, thank you for the tips! Should I edit the question to make it more clear?

Comment: Elaborating my hint, try to write each $\mathbf{w}$ satisfying $\langle\mathbf{w},\mathbf{x}\rangle=1$ as $$\mathbf{w}=\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^2}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{v}$$ for some $\mathbf{v}$ that is orthogonal to $\mathbf{x}$, and conversely, any $\mathbf{w}$ given by the above form satisfies $\langle\mathbf{w},\mathbf{x}\rangle=1$. Also, I believe that your answer is drawing close votes because you did not show your own attempts, thoughts, etc., so you may try improving your answer in this regard. We enforce [quality standard](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/9340) here.